How to assign values from a list to variables from a list in python?
I have some code that is asking users questions and storing the responses in a list. I then want to assign the response values to variables from a list. Its not working as expected though as it doesnt look like the variables exist when I try and use them later in my script. I've seen a few similar questions on here and tried a few things out but nothing is working
questions = ['Please enter your gross annual salary: ', 'Please enter the annual amount of any bonus or commision that appears on your paylip. If not applicable enter 0: ', 'Please enter the annual amount of any benefits in kind that appear on your payslip. If not applicable enter 0: ', 'Please enter your annual total tax credit: ', 'Please enter your annual total pension contribution. If not applicable enter 0: ', 'Do you have any other non tax deductable income? (ie. Holiday purchase schemes etc.) If not applicable enter 0: ']
variables = ['salary', 'bonus', 'bik', 'tax_credits', 'pension_contributions', 'other_non_tax_deductibles']
responses = []
for question in questions:
    while True:
        try:
            response = float(input({question}))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a number")
        else:
            responses.append(response)
            break
for variable, response in zip(variables, responses): 
    variable = response


Use a dictionary, not separate variables.

You can use a dictionary:

def _get_responses(questions, variables):
    res = {}
    for question, variable in zip(questions, variables):
        while True:
            try:
                response = float(input(question))
            except ValueError:
                print("Please enter a number")
            else:
                res[variable] = response
                break
    return res


def _function_one(res, *args, **kwargs):
    pass  # do something


def _function_two(salary, *args, **kwargs):
    pass  # do something else


def _function_three(salary, other_non_tax_deductibles, *args, **kwargs):
    pass  # do something else


questions = [
    'Please enter your gross annual salary: ',
    'Please enter the annual amount of any bonus or commission that appears on your payslip. If not applicable enter 0: ',
    'Please enter the annual amount of any benefits in kind that appear on your payslip. If not applicable enter 0: ',
    'Please enter your annual total tax credit: ',
    'Please enter your annual total pension contribution. If not applicable enter 0: ',
    'Do you have any other non-tax deductible income? (i.e., Holiday purchase schemes etc.) If not applicable enter 0: '
]
variables = ['salary', 'bonus', 'bik', 'tax_credits', 'pension_contributions', 'other_non_tax_deductibles']

responses = _get_responses(questions, variables)


_function_one(responses)
_function_two(responses['salary'])
_function_three(responses['salary'], responses['other_non_tax_deductibles'])




ah okay that makes sense. and so if I want to pass the variables then to other functions do I pass them as res[salary] for example?

@DeirdreRodgers That's correct. Updated for that.
